# Storing data to a dto object inside another dto

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, criteria

Consider I have a DTO as follows

```
SampleChildDTO {
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
}
```

This DTO is represented inside another DTO

```
ParentDTO{
   private String parentID;
   *private SampleChildDTO child*;
}
```

I am using *Criteria* to generate queries to get data from **Parent** class and store data to **ParentDTO** object using *Tranformers.aliasToBean()*.

But I wanted to use just one call to store the data for **Child** class which is mapped in **Parent** and this data should go to the object for **SampleChildDTO** *inside* **ParentDTO**. Is there any way to achieve this than writing a separate query?

Comment: You need to map `PArentDTO` and `SampleChildDTO`. Have you done that?

Comment: Ideally we can  Map.Follow the link ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628759/java-hibernate-criteria-setresulttransformertransformers-aliastobeanstudentm

Comment: @DarshanLila I have mapped the fields in Parent and Child entities. Did you mean that?

Comment: @SK08... I have already mapped fields from an entity to that in dto using projections, but I want to know if it is possible to have a child dto's object in parentDto and have the fields in child filled using projections.